# Connect to Docker SQL Server container from asp.net core container

Tags: sql-server, docker-compose, .net-6.0

I have two containers which are supposed to talk to each other. One is ASP.NET Core 6 and the other one is SQL Server 2019. The YAML file is as follows:

```
version: "3.8"

services:
  psbackendapi:
    depends_on:
      - sqldb
    image: ${DOCKER_REGISTRY-}psbackendapi
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: PSBackEndAPI/Dockerfile
    ports:
      - "5000:80"
      - "5001:443"
    environment:
      - ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT= Development
      - ASPNETCORE_URLS=https://+:443;http://+:80
      - ASPNETCORE_Kestrel__Certificates__Default__Password=crypticpassword
      - ASPNETCORE_Kestrel__Certificates__Default__Path=/https/aspnetapp.pfx
      - DBServer= sqldb
      - DBDatabase= FilmDB
      - DBPort= 1450
      - DBUser= SA
      - DBPassword= 2Secure*Password2
    
    volumes:
      - ~/.aspnet/https:/https:ro
  sqldb:
    image: mcr.microsoft.com/mssql/server:2019-latest
    environment:
      - SA_PASSWORD=2Secure*Password2
      - ACCEPT_EULA=Y
    ports:
      - 1450:1433
```

And the Dockerfile is as below:

```
#See https://aka.ms/containerfastmode to understand how Visual Studio uses this Dockerfile to build your images for faster debugging.

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:6.0 AS base
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 80
EXPOSE 443


FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:6.0 AS build
WORKDIR /src
COPY ["PSBackEndAPI/PSBackEndAPI.csproj", "PSBackEndAPI/"]
COPY ["PSBackEndAPI.Model/PSBackEndAPI.Model.csproj", "PSBackEndAPI.Model/"]
COPY ["PSBackEndAPI.Data/PSBackEndAPI.Data.csproj", "PSBackEndAPI.Data/"]
COPY ["PSBackEndAPI.Contract/PSBackEndAPI.Contract.csproj", "PSBackEndAPI.Contract/"]
COPY ["PSBackEndAPI.Core/PSBackEndAPI.Core.csproj", "PSBackEndAPI.Core/"]
RUN dotnet restore "PSBackEndAPI/PSBackEndAPI.csproj"
COPY . .
WORKDIR "/src/PSBackEndAPI"
RUN dotnet build "PSBackEndAPI.csproj" -c Release -o /app/build

FROM build AS publish
RUN dotnet publish "PSBackEndAPI.csproj" -c Release -o /app/publish

FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app/publish .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "PSBackEndAPI.dll"]
```

And this is the piece of code that builds connection string:

```
var server = builder.Configuration["DBServer"] ?? "sqldb";
var port = builder.Configuration["DBPort"] ?? "1450";
var database = builder.Configuration["DBDatabase"] ?? "FilmDB";
var user = builder.Configuration["DBUser"] ?? "SA";
var password = builder.Configuration["DBPassword"] ?? "2Secure*Password2";
var connection = $"Database={database}; Server={server},{port}; User={user};Password={password}";
builder.Services.AddSqlServerDbContextFactory<FilmContext>(connection);
```

As far as I know everything is correct but when I run docker-compose command I get this error:
[image]

Moreover, I can easily connect to SQL server through Sql Server Management Studio:

[image]

Comment: It seems that you're specifying that the `host:container` port mapping is `1450:1433`, meaning that the Docker host's port 1450 tunnels through to the container's port 1433. Have you tried either `host.docker.internal,1450` or `sqldb,1433` in your builder configuration?

Comment: Yes, but no use!!

Comment: Don't forget you need to add `--build` to your launch command since the `psbackendapi` container image has been built previously, i.e.: `docker compose up --build`

Comment: Again the same error

Comment: @aminmohammadi are you able to connect to SQL when you run the debugger?

Answer (score 0):

You must put both the .net container and the sql server in the same docker network

https://github.com/microsoft/msphpsql/issues/302#issuecomment-361439294